# Pass statement doesnt alter my program

Tags: python-3.5

for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:

```
if i==3:  
    pass
    print ("Pass when value is",i)  
print (i)
```

for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:

```
if i==3:        
    print ("Pass when value is",i)  
print (i)
```

I get the same output for both the codes.
Then what is the use of pass statement here.

Answer (score 1):

`pass` is used when the syntax requires a statement but you don't want to do anything.

Example:

```
def foo(bar):
    pass # does nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

`pass` is a "do nothing" statement. In this case, it's indeed pointless. It was created to come in place on logically empty blocks, which Python does not allow (unlike [c](/questions/tagged/c) or [java](/questions/tagged/java), for example). E.g.:

```
try:
    doSomething()
catch ExpectedException:
   # We expect this, do nothing
   pass
catch OtherException:
   # Oh no, something bad happened
   handleOtherException()
```